# Watson AlchemyLanguage - How do I set the parameters for a CombinedCall

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, alchemyapi

Unfortunately I can't properly tag this question since tags for AlchemyLanguage don't already exist.
I'm trying to retrieve multiple extracts from Watson using a combined call.
Issuing calls for individual data extracts works as expected, but when I attempt to setup params for a combined call only null is returned for each extract.
According to the examples utilizing JSON it seems that 'extract':'sentiment' is the required pairing.

None of these calls work:

```
params.put(AlchemyLanguage.EXTRACT, AlchemyLanguage.SENTIMENT);
params.put(AlchemyLanguage.EXTRACT, AlchemyEndPoints.AlchemyAPI.SENTIMENT);
params.put(AlchemyLanguage.EXTRACT, DocumentSentiment.class);
params.put(AlchemyLanguage.TARGET, AlchemyEndPoints.AlchemyAPI.SENTIMENT);
params.put(AlchemyLanguage.TARGET, DocumentSentiment.class);
params.put(AlchemyLanguage.TARGET, AlchemyLanguage.SENTIMENT);

CombinedResults results=service.getCombinedResults(params).execute();
System.out.println(results.getSentiment());
```

**null**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `extract` parameter as key and list the functions you want to use.

```
AlchemyLanguage service = new AlchemyLanguage();
service.setApiKey("API_KEY")
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

params.put(AlchemyLanguage.EXTRACT, "authors,concepts,dates,doc-emotion,entities,feeds,keywords,pub-date,relations,typed-rels,doc-sentiment,taxonomy,title");

CombinedResults results=service.getCombinedResults(params).execute();
System.out.println(results);
```

For more information on how to configure each of the functions listed in the `extract` parameter see the [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/alchemy-language/api/v1/?curl#combined-call).